# How to be sure that a loop performed with for and seq is executed a number of times known in advance

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

I would like to write a `for` loop, in a way that I know for sure how many times it will be executed. I would also like the first and last element of the vector I will loop on, to be fixed. I'm not sure I can "have it all". A concrete example:

```
step <- 0.1
lambda.min <- 0.1
nlambda <- 99
lambda.max <- lambda.min + nlambda*step
lambdas <- seq(lambda.min, lambda.max, len = nlambda)
mu.lambda <- vector(mode = "numeric", len = nlambda)
i <- 0
for (lambda in lambdas) {
    a <- 2*lambda-3
    i <- i + 1
    mu.lambda[i]  <- a
}
```

I think this way is the correct way in R to define a loop which will be executed exactly `nlambda` times, because `lambda` is a vector of length `nlambda`. Thus also `mu.lambda` will be of length exactly `nlambda`, because the loop is executed `nlambda` times, so no runtime growth of `mu.lambda` can happen. However, 
I cannot prescrive `lambda.max`: it will only be "exact" up to roundoff error. If I want `lambda.max` to be exactly a certain value, should I modify `lambdas` this way?

```
lambda.max <- 1
lambdas[nlambda] <- lambda.max
```

Or are there safer/simpler/more idiomatic ways to do this? I don't think

```
step <- 0.1
lambda.min <- 0.1
lambda.max <- 1
lambdas <- seq(lambda.min, lambda.max, by = step)
```

would be better, because then I'm not sure the loop is executed exactly 99 times, which is my first priority.

Comment: `seq` has a length.out argument which may be useful here. Something like `lambdas <- seq(lambda.min, lambda.max, length.out=100)`.

Comment: @JosephWood whoops, you're right, I fixed the `i` issue. Concerning the `sapply` solution, the actual code executed in the loop is more complicated (it's basically Importance Sampling, if you're familiar with it). It would be not as easy to use `sapply`, but, sure, if you think it's a good idea, I could include the real code that has to be executed and you could tell me if you still think `sapply` would trump a `for` code in terms of speed and readability. In that case, I would have no objections in going the `sapply` way.

Comment: @lmo yes, it's the same as my `len` argument. So I should specify `lambda.min`, `lambda.max`, `nlambda`, and just let R figure out the `step` size required.  So obvious that I'm considering deleting the question :P

Comment: A lot of these utility functions have hidden gems like this argument, not always needed, but a life-saver now and again.